# Magento2 - How to create sitemap pro-grammatically with custom script

Tags: magento2, xml, sitemaps

I want to create sitemap pro-grammatically using script,

any one have idea, to create sitemap using API or another way...

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom code as given below to generate sitemap.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class TestGenerateSitemap {
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap $sitemap
    ) {
        $this->sitemap = $sitemap;
    }

    public function createSitemapXml() {
        $this->sitemap->setSitemapFilename('sitemap.xml');
        $this->sitemap->generateXml();
    }
}
```

and call `Vendor\Module\Model\TestGenerateSitemap::createSitemapXml()` from anywhere to generate the sitemap.

You can also create an api or console command and utilize `\Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap::generateXml()` function to create the sitemap.